# EF7 .NET Core 1 RC2 Add-Migration failing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-rc2

I recently installed .NET Core 1.0 RC2, and I know that the command DNX have changed to the dotnet.exe command, But know I can't found how to create new EF7 Migration file.
Whatever I try the "dotnet ef" command 
I get

```
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No executable f...and "dotnet-ef":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

And something similar,  if a try the "Add-Migration" command from within the VS PS Console witch give me this :

```
Add-Migration : The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Migration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-Migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm googling since 3 hours without any result.

I feel like a package is missing.

Is someone here have successfully created a new EF7 migration class. after installing RC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've founded the solution ...

You need to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package to your projets

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I decremented this post as the link is broken. Please fix and I'll increment.

Answer (score 3):

The commands are in [Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/1.0.0-preview1-final) package, so run following command in the Package Manager Console (or add the package through the NuGet package manager UI):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre
```

A few days ago I pushed a small app with EF Core 1 RC2 to [GitHub](https://github.com/bartlannoeye/SO-Dump/tree/master/20160522%20-%20EF), in which the Add-Migration worked. You can use it as a reference if necessary.

Comment: Thank to the reply. 
The package fail to install. The package seam to not be available


  NotFound https://dotnetmyget.blob.core.windows.net/artifacts/dotnet-cli/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/1.0.0-preview2-21074/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.1.0.0-preview2-21074.nupkg 415ms
Install failed. Rolling back...

Comment: You seem to be getting the package from the myget feed? It's available on NuGet already and downloads from there (just double checked)

Comment: It's like I had to add the package manually to the projet.json file (https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/cli/dotnet.html#install-by-editing-project-json) now I can call the "dotnet EF" Command. But now i'm facing a new probleme witch tell me "dotnet : This preview of Entity Framework tools does not support targeting class library projects in ASP.NET Core and .NET Core applications. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for details and 
workarounds."

Comment: I suppose that's the difference between UWP and ASP.NET Core. Didn't know which of both you used as the question didn't state it. Good to hear you're already a step further.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue.

in Visual Studio option Powershell interactive console.

then go to the directory you project is in. I needed to be in the same directory that had the project file. then run dotnet ef that shows the dotnet ef commandline help data.